# Is there an immutable ID to use with the UWP Contact Picker?

Tags: windows, uwp, contactpicker

Contacts do not appear to keep the same ID after edits. In a UWP app:

1. Launch custom UWP app, user clicks "Add Contact"
2. Call contactPicker.PickContactAsync()
3. User selects contact, returns a Contact with an ID such as **{5.70002.836}**
4. Save Contact ID
5. Close UWP app
6. Launch People, change contact picture, close People
7. Launch custom UWP app
8. Call contactStore.GetContactAsync(savedContactId) <- this returns null
9. Call contactPicker.PickContactAsync(), select *same* contact
10. Returned correct Contact, however, ID is now **{5.70002.849}**

Is that the correct behavior? Is there some other way of tracking the same contact in a UWP app between sessions?

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps you said, but it didn't reproduce. You can try to create a new contact and repeat your operation to see if this problem can be reproduced steadily (P.S. My system version is 18363)

Comment: Reproduced with a new contact, however, it took longer.

I created a new contact, did the steps above, no issue. Then went in and set the birthdate, kept trying UWP with no issues until after about ten minutes the contact wasn't found. I went into People, it wasn't there. Waited another ~ten minutes, contact was back. Went to UWP, the ID changed from {5.70002.84c} to {5.70002.84d}

FYI - OS 18363, People syncs with my O365 work/school account

Comment: After mentioning O365 above... I did all of the same steps for an existing and a new contact. However used the O365 web interface instead of People, same issues.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot reproduce the problem. By design, Concact.Id is unchanged unless rebuilt. In the description you mentioned that the contact had disappeared in `People` and the Id changed when it appeared again. Reconstruction should occur at this time, which will cause the Id to change. It's not clear what caused it, you can try to test it on other devices or disconnect from O365.